# Ошибка NullPointerException при запуске кода

Tags: java, android

Изучил подобные вопросы заданные здесь ранее, об этой же ошибке, но т.к. только начал программировать ответов для своей задачи не нашел. 
Код программы:

```
package com.evreal.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button start;
TextView message;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     switch (v.getId()) {
                                         case R.id.start:
                                             message.setText("Hello world");
                                             break;
                                         default:
                                             break;
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
    );
}
}
```

Разметка Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.evreal.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Evreal"
            android:id="@+id/evreal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="#01c017"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Do this"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

при запуске выдает следующие ошибки:

> 03-23 02:03:52.674 20433-20433/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.evreal.myapplication/com.evreal.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at com.evreal.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

видимо ошибка в строке 22 кода

> start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

но как её решить не знаю.

Почему возвращает Null и что не правильно?
Также почему столько ошибок выдает?
И правильно ли я предположил причину фатальной ошибки?

Код данного метода вроде соответствует требованиям справочной документации из http://developer.android.com

Comment: Вы всерьез думаете, что этой ошибки не появилось бы, запустив свой код в Eclipse с стандартным эмулятором ? Меньше ненужной воды в вопросах, меньше жирного шрифта и тройных вопросительных знаков, пожалуйста. Тег [android-studio] для вопросов по решению проблем в работе самой IDE, а не для демонстрации в чем вы пишите код - это не существенно в данном случае.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @metalurgus - столько ошибок потому, что это стектрейс и здесь представлена вся цепочка "крушения" приложения, вызванная вашей невнимательностью. То есть - от обнаружения, что виджета с данным ID нет и до падения по этой причине где то "в глубинах системы".  **IDE должна была подсвечивать вашу `R.id.start` красным**, разве нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В разметке у вашей кнопки id такой:

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

А найти ее вы пытаетесь по такому айди:

```
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
```

Всего лишь внимательность и умение пользоваться отладчиком уберегут от таких ошибок

Comment: Спасибо) Всю критику принял.

Comment: IDE к сожалению не выделил красным R.id.start

Comment: @AndUp, не выделил потому, что в другом файле разметки у вас есть другой `View` с таким `id`